# Use Method inside Asycronous TCPSocketListener

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

I try to use asycronous TCP-Sockets but I encountered a problem:

```
 private  void  Client_Received(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        if (ar.IsCompleted)
        {
            var state = ar.AsyncState as ClientStateObject;
            var bytesIn = state.Stream.EndRead(ar);
            if (bytesIn > 0)
            {
                msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.Buffer, 0, bytesIn);
                print($"From client: {msg}");
                String[] strlist = msg.Split('/');
                setSaveFile(strlist[0], strlist[1]);

                


               
            }
            var newState = new ClientStateObject(state.Client);
            state.Stream.BeginRead(state.Buffer, 0, state.Buffer.Length, Client_Received, newState);

        }
```

I the above code the setSaveFile method seems not to get called. The print and everything else is execute. Could the reason be that you cant simple call an method from an externally referenced calls here ?

Comment: it sounds like, the msg is null, reading from the buffer, then you get a NullReferenceException in "msg.Split(....)". That might be the reason why print is executed and not setSaveFile. Do some try catches there and read from the state.Stream and not from state.Buffer. The buffer is not ther to read from, its for buffering. Enable Exceptions in your dev tools to find out where exceptions happens

Comment: no the msg is not null. I checked this. The print, prints the message. Also the split is printable. Only the last methods does not get executed and I dont get anything from the compiler. I have several print() inside the method but nothing seems to happen.

Comment: I figured it out. It had nothing to do with the async. The reason was something else. Thanks for your help anyways.